# Cannot track a form submission with Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, form-submit

I know the methods of tracking a form submission but in this case unfortunately I couldn't make it. Once the form is submitted, you can see in the debug mode that the exact same variables fire as in the case that the user tried to submit that form and it failed (because some fields weren't filled in). So the variables of GTM upon submitting don't help.

I tried another approach, with the url redirect. But the thing is that the redirection is to site.com/buy?add-to-cart, and this parameter causes adding to cart and then it redirects to the checkout page. This checkout page can be reached from many places so I can't track the form submission with page view either.

I don't know what to do already, is there another way that I didn't think of?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it possible to add a unique key value to DataLayer on successful form submission? If so you can use that as the trigger for the tag.

Comment: Thank you badman that's what I did thanks(:

Comment: No worries, glad it’s working 